# USB Hard drive diagnostic tool

Tags: hard-drive, usb, diagnostic

I have a Freecom 500GB Toughdrive and I have a suspicion that something is wrong with it, because my PC sometimes does not find it and it sometimes makes clicking sounds.  The drive itself is not that old, however I want to be sure that it's ok, as it contains vital data.

Does anyone know of USB HDD Diagnostics Utility that will tell me the condition of my drive?

I have tried ActiveSmart for USB drives but it does not find my disk.

It's formatted in FAT32, I wondered if I should re-format it in NTFS?  Will this make it last longer?

Comment: Is it a IDE or SATA... or SCSI

Comment: its a USB disk, external

Comment: This is the interface. But this HDD is IDE or SATA?

Comment: I don't know... I'm not sure how to find out either, do you know?

Answer (score 1):

If a drive makes clicking sound, gets the data off of it NOW.
If it contains vital data, then money to replace it is not an issue, because the data's more important than the money. Get a new drive.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have it in NTFS format for security settings and space management.

You can take a look at this web site for HDD checkup tools.

http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=287